# Error whilst using any sudo command

Tags: command-line, sudo, pop-os

Whenever I use the sudo command, I get the following error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host josphh-pop-os: Name or service not known
```

Usually with things like `sudo apt install` it shows the error and then runs, but with other commands it just produces that error and nothing more. I'm currently running Pop_OS if that is any help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Contents of the file `/etc/sudoers`:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:>

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Please add the contents of the file `/etc/sudoers` by editing your question. Use the "code" feature while editing to format the file contents here so it is readable.

Comment: Use the `id` command to make sure you are inside the groups `admin` or `sudo`. Also, does the problem persist if you reboot the machine?

Comment: @Hobber after using the command `id`, I get the following message
`uid=1000(josphh) gid=1000(josphh) groups=1000(josphh),4(adm),27(sudo)`

And also no, the problem persists after reboot.

Comment: What files exist in the /etc/sudoers.d/ directory?

Comment: @glennjackman just a `README` file

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because you don't have a hostname (perhaps corrupt installation?), try editing `/etc/hostname` by doing `sudo nano /etc/hostname` and write a name for your computer.

Comment: It seems that there's already a hostname in that file, I've changed it but i still get the same `sudo` error.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the command `hostname` (or the `Static hostname` field of the command `hostnamectl`) should match the hostname written in the file `/etc/hostname`.

The file `/etc/hosts` should also contain something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
127.0.1.1   yourHostName.localdomain    yourHostName
```

An error in some of these files may be the cause for your problem.

You will probably need sudo privileges to fix that. But you are precisely unable to run `sudo`, so if you have the option, try logging as root:

```
su
```

Comment: When opening the file `/etc/hosts` I get exactly what you specified. And when running `hostname`, I get the exact name as in the file `/etc/hostname`